# Why does GNU parted write data to the first 440 bytes of the MBR?

Tags: mbr, parted

My understanding is that an MBR is 512 bytes. The [first 440 bytes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fdisk#Using_dd) ([give](https://wiki.osdev.org/MBR_(x86)#MBR_Format) or [take](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Sector_layout) a [few](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fdisk#Using_dd) [bytes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254657/mbr-size-is-440-bytes-or-512-bytes), depending on the implementation) contain the boot loader/bootstrap code area. The remaining bytes contain information about the partition table.

If I zero out the MBR of a disk...

```
# Zero out the MBR
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1 count=512
```

Then, use `fdisk` to write a partition table to `/dev/sdX`...

```
# Create a 2GiB partition starting at 2048 (default).
fdisk /dev/sdX

...
Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier ...
...

(fdisk) n
(fdisk) p
(fdisk) 1
(fdisk) 2048
(fdisk) +2G
(fdisk) w
```

And then read back the first 440 bytes...

```
dd if=/dev/sdX bs=1 count=440
```

The first `440` bytes are still all zero. `fdisk` did not touch them, which makes sense based on the links I posted above. `fdisk` is writing partition information, so it should/would not need to touch the first `440`.

The next `6` bytes are non-zero. I'm assuming these bytes are part of the [disk signature of a modern standard MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Sector_layout).

```
$ dd if=/dev/sdX bs=1 count=6 skip=440 | hexdump -e '4/1 "%02x " "\n"'
9a 29 97 e7
```

So far, that makes sense with my understanding of how the MBR is laid out. Those first `440` bytes are ignored by `fdisk` because they're the domain of the bootloader, and `fdisk` is only concerned with partition tables.

However, `parted` is throwing me for a loop.

If I zero out the MBR of that same disk again...

```
# Zero out the MBR
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1 count=512
```

Then, use parted to create a disk label (which `fdisk` seemed to do automatically for me up above)...

```
parted /dev/sdX mklabel msdos
```

And then read back the first `440` bytes...

```
$ dd if=/dev/sdX bs=1 count=440 | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x " "\n"'
fa b8 00 10 8e d0 bc 00 b0 b8 00 00 8e d8 8e c0
fb be 00 7c bf 00 06 b9 00 02 f3 a4 ea 21 06 00
00 be be 07 38 04 75 0b 83 c6 10 81 fe fe 07 75
f3 eb 16 b4 02 b0 01 bb 00 7c b2 80 8a 74 01 8b
4c 02 cd 13 ea 00 7c 00 00 eb fe 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

**There are non-zero bytes!** That does not seem to make sense with my current understanding of how the MBR should be laid out and what GNU parted is [supposed to accomplish](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html).

> GNU Parted is a program for creating and manipulating partition tables.

Why is `parted` writing data to those first `440` bytes? Aren't those bytes meant for a bootloader? Shouldn't parted leave those bytes alone like `fdisk` did?

Comment: Have you tried to boot the disk partitioned with Parted?

Comment: I had not tried that until you suggested it. I get a black screen when I boot to that disk. It's interesting that I'm not seeing something like `No bootable medium found!`. That's the error I get if I boot to a completely blank disk. So it seems like `parted` is writing some sort of quasi-valid boot loader code that BIOS is trying to execute, but it's not enough on its own.

Comment: I would guess that this is a bug in Parted, best discussed in its forums, which seem to be [here](http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/).

Answer (score 3):

It would appear I am [not](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parted/2017-02/msg00001.html) the [only](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parted/2017-02/msg00004.html) one to [notice](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parted/2014-08/msg00008.html) this behavior. It seems to especially be an issue for some `arm` environments where having a bootloader on the disk can cause issues.

> The problem is that parted itself (and silently) puts the code there
>   and hence the embedded system thinks that there is a valid
>   bootloader code and happily hangs.

...and...

> Is there any option to parted to avoid adding this code (and behave like fdisk)?

It seems that this behavior by `parted` is [intentional](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parted/2017-02/msg00001.html). As a user on the `parted` mailing lisk asks:

> The problem is that parted is generating following code from the very beginning of the MBR:
>
> ...
>
> What is the purpose of this code? Why is has been put there?

And the answer seems to be:

> That's the MBR boot code normally used to boot a BIOS system. If it
>   causes problems on a non-x86 system you should zero it out (or write the
>   system bootloader after partitioning).

It seems that `mklabel` is designed to write a generic bootloader to the disk. At least, when a label of `msdos` is being used. I *suppose* that makes sense, but coming from `fdisk` and `syslinux`, it seems a bit unusual for a partition manager to modify bootloader sectors.

It [seems](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parted/2017-02/msg00004.html) like `parted` should *not* be overwriting those sectors if non-zero data is present.

> No, the only time it won't write it is if there is something already there (eg. not 0x00). So if you could get the SDK to write it's bootloader first, then partition it, parted will leave it untouched.

However, that is *not* the behavior I am seeing. If I write garbage from `/dev/urandom`, then run `parted mklabel`, my non-zero data is definitely being clobbered.

If I assemble the `mbr.s` file in `libparted` from the [parted repo](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parted/), I can see where those bytes are coming from.

```
$ as86 -b /dev/stdout mbr.s | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x " "\n"'
fa b8 00 10 8e d0 bc 00 b0 b8 00 00 8e d8 8e c0
fb be 00 7c bf 00 06 b9 00 02 f3 a4 ea 21 06 00
00 be be 07 38 04 75 0b 83 c6 10 81 fe fe 07 75
f3 eb 16 b4 02 b0 01 bb 00 7c b2 80 8a 74 01 8b
4c 02 cd 13 ea 00 7c 00 00 eb fe
```

That is **exactly** the byte sequence that `parted` seems to generate on my disk.